# How do i print every 3rd number in a list in python WITHOUT USING slice notation (square brackets)?

Tags: python

```
def every_third(lst):
    '''
    every_third that takes a list as a parameter and returns
    a new list that contains every third element of the original
    list, starting at index 0.

    >>> every_third([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    [1,4,7,10]
```

How would I do this? I know that we can use a for loop, but i just dont know how to begin.

Comment: I think you forgot to include what approaches you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) is allowed with all of `start`, `stop`, `step` (which is not exactly slice notation), just do:

```
def every_third(lst):
   return [lst[i] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
```

If not, use a conditional comprehension with a condition based on modulo:

```
def every_third(lst):
   return [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i%3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick using `enumerate`:

```
seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
every_three = [value for idx, value in enumerate(seq) if idx % 3 == 0]
```

But my first comment if code review of lines above would be: *Use slice syntax, there's no need to use an enumerate here*.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just the slice notation, as in [::3] I think it should be somethink like this, I figure You are doing exercises right?

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def third(list):
    res=[]
    count=3
    res.append(list[0])
    while len(list)>0:

        if count>0:
            list.pop(0)
        else:
            res.append(list[0])
            list.pop(0)
            count=3
        count -= 1
    return res

print(third(list))
```